# My Modal buttons aren't working anymore

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-modal

```
<div class="col-sm-5 col-sm-offset-2">
        <div class="thumbnail">
            <img class="img-responsive" src="https://www.svdj.nl/wp-content/uploads/2015/10/18349600659.jpg">
            <div class="caption">
                <h2>Projects<strong></strong></h2>
                <p>
                <h3>PHP, Javascript, Elements, HTML/CSS en nog veel meer.. lees hier over de dagelijkse
                    werkzaamheden
                    en verantwoordelijkheden</h3>
                <!--button trigger modal-->
                <button href="#" class="btn btn-default" data-toggle="modal" data-target="modal">More!</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<!--MODAL-->
<div class="modal" role="dialog">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <!-- Modal inhoud-->
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
                <h3 class="modal-title">projecten</h3>
                <div class="modal-body">
                    <p class="modalText">
                        Als stagiare werd ik enorm gedrilt om heel veel competenties en kwaliteiten aan te leren.
                        Dit werd gedaan door elke dag bezig te zijn met verschillende cursussen en daarna resultaat
                        te leveren door middel van opdrachten. Hierdoor werd de kennis constant getoetst en kon
                        mijn begeleider zien of ik het wel had begrepen. Daarnaast was het voor hun een meting om
                        te kijken of ik het wel aan kon en voldoende capaciteiten had voor het bedrijf.

                    </p>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-footer">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Sluiten</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I've made a thumbnail which has a button which activates a modal. But all of a sudden it stopped working and i honestly dont know what happend. I didnt delete anything and i have been searching my code for mistakes but i can't find it.

Maybe some more experienced coders could find it, as i am a complete noob..

Comment: Provide jsfiddle.

Comment: How do i do that ?
I went to jfiddle and inserted my code what now?

Comment: Add external library as bootstrap, click save and give us the link.

Comment: I dont know what you mean.. 
On the side it says add library and than .. ?

Comment: Never mind. I solved it..

Comment: The data-target didnt match the div class modal.  nooooob i know

Answer (score 0):

the attribute of modal-target expects a selector change it to

```
<button href="#" class="btn btn-default" data-toggle="modal" data-target=".modal">More!</button>
```